# How could I extract the code of a method dynamically using reflection or something similar?

Tags: c#, reflection

I've written a modular sandbox that is intended to be a living portfolio of sorts, and it's working great so far, but I had an idea for it that I can't seem to figure out how to do. As a quick overview, when I have a new idea, or want to test a new concept, I write a module for it. Each module derives from `SandboxModule` which contains an abstract method called `Execute`. When I create a module, it looks a little something like this:

```
public class DemoModule : SandboxModule {
    protected override void Execute() {
        // Do something super cool and new.
    }
}
```

There's nothing that prevents me from creating additional methods to call from the `Execute` method, just as I could in any other custom object:

```
public class DemoModule : SandboxModule {
    protected override void Execute() {
        int x = 3;
        SomethingSuperCoolAndNew(x);
    }
    private void SomethingSuperCoolAndNew(int someArg) {
        // Do something super cool and new.
    }
}
```

How do I capture the code contents of the `Execute` method, and any methods it may call, any they may call, etc, as a `string`, in a dynamic fashion, such as using reflection?

---

**NOTES**: I'm not against using third party libraries if I must. Though if it can be done without them, I'd prefer that route with respect to the nature of the sandbox.

I've already looked into using [`MethodBas.GetMethodBody()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody?view=netcore-3.1), it does not return what I'm wanting to display.

One idea that might work, would be to load the source file from my GitHub repo. I'll give that a try in the meantime, but I still wonder if there's a way to do it without jumping through that hoop?

Comment: What do you want to do with "the code contents" after you capture it?

Comment: The compiled code does not contain the C# source. It contains [Intermediate Language (IL)](https://www.dotnetperls.com/il). But why do you need the know which methods are called?

Comment: @GuruStron I want to display the code within the module summary that I display when a module is selected. This way, you can not only execute the module, you can see the code that powers it. Worst case I can always link to the GitHub file instead, which just gave me an idea... I think I can load the file from GitHub and parse from that :D wouldn't that be something?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes because it's not a complete representation of the execution code if I don't display the methods that are called. Now, this doesn't mean I want the code for some MS method or the code from a third party lib, I'm focused purely on what's available in the same assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection allows you to discover the class members like properties or methods, but it only gives information on their signature (parameter names and types and return type etc.) but no information about their implementation.

---

If you have access to the source code, you can use the C# compiler to do a syntax analysis for you.

See: [Get started with syntax analysis (The .NET Compiler Platform SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/syntax-analysis).

Especially the [Traversing trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/syntax-analysis#traversing-trees) chapter explains how you can discover the structure of your code.

---

But maybe a better way to document your code is to use XML-comments (also called [Documentation comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/documentation-comments)).

In the project options in the `Build` page, check the `XML documentation file` check box and then write comments like these:

```
/// <summary>
/// Base module for sandboxed operations.
/// </summary>
public abstract class SandboxModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implementing modues must override this method.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void Execute();
}

/// <summary>
/// This is my super cool demo module.
/// </summary>
public class DemoModule : SandboxModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Does something super cool and new.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>It does so by calling the private method <c>SomethingSuperCoolAndNew</c>.</remarks>
    protected override void Execute()
    {
        int x = 3;
        SomethingSuperCoolAndNew(x);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Important things happen here.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="someArg">Magic parameter.</param>
    private void SomethingSuperCoolAndNew(int someArg)
    {
        // Do something super cool and new.
    }
}
```

In the output directory (bin\Debug) the compiler will create an XML file looking like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>StackOverflowTests3</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:StackOverflowTests3.SandboxModule">
            <summary>
            Base module for sandboxed operations.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:StackOverflowTests3.SandboxModule.Execute">
            <summary>
            Implementing modues must override this method.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="T:StackOverflowTests3.DemoModule">
            <summary>
            This is my super cool demo module.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:StackOverflowTests3.DemoModule.Execute">
            <summary>
            Does something super cool and new.
            </summary>
            <remarks>It does so by calling the private method <c>SomethingSuperCoolAndNew</c>.</remarks>
        </member>
        <member name="M:StackOverflowTests3.DemoModule.SomethingSuperCoolAndNew(System.Int32)">
            <summary>
            Important things happen here.
            </summary>
            <param name="someArg">Magic parameter.</param>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

This Visual Studio Magazine article explains how you can convert these XML-files into help files: [Doing Visual Studio and .NET Code Documentation Right](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/02/21/vs-dotnet-code-documentation-tools-roundup.aspx).

The documentations comments are even visible within Visual Studio's IntelliSense tooltips.

Comment: Oh this is perfect! Not quite the way I wanted to do it I think, but with access to the GitHub files, I can easily use this to supply at least the execute method! Traversing multiple files may get a little slow over time. Thank you so much!